# jQuery short script for image swapping with multiple classes

Tags: jquery, html, image, function, click

I wrote a short script for swapping big images by clicking the thumbnail.
This should work on every item itself but by clicking a thumb, all big images are swapping.

This is what i have many times:

```
<div class="item_page_itemlist" style="">
<div class="item">          
    <span class="number"></span>
    <div class="pos">
        <div class="inner">
            <div id="listWrapper" class="clistWrapper clistWrapper[ID]"></div>
            <style>
                .clistWrapper[ID] {
                    background: url('/images/products/img1234.png');
                    background-size: cover;
                    -moz-background-size: cover;
                    -webkit-background-size: cover;
                    -o-background-size: cover;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                }
            </style>
        </div><!-- inner -->
        <div class="rightinner">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <div class="propslist">
                <p class="pone"><span>Measures: </span>0 x 0 x 0cm</p>
                <p class="ptwo"><span>Material: </span>Wood</p>
                <p class="pthree"><span>Weight: </span>65kg</p>
            </div>
            <div class="listThumbCon">
                <div id="listThumb" class="listThumbs listThumbs[ID]">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="/images/produkte/cache/mi11/11.jpg"></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="/images/produkte/cache/mi12/12.jpg"></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="/images/produkte/cache/mi13/13.jpg"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--item-->
```

The jQuery:

```
$(".listThumbs img").click(function(){
    //console.log($(this).attr("src"));
    var newImg = $(this).attr("src");
    $(".clistWrapper", this).css("background-image","url('"+newImg+"')");
});
```

It is not possible to use the [ID] which is generated. I mean, it is possible and by using the [ID] for each item but I do not want to have the script for every single item.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the ID, you don't have to re-write the script for every ID, you can use the jQuery "Starts with" selector;
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

For example;

```
$('div[id^="listThumb"]')........
```

That would then work for:

```
<div id="listThumb1">....</div>
<div id="listThumb2">....</div>
<div id="listThumb3">....</div>
<div id="listThumb4">....</div>
<div id="listThumb5">....</div>
```

etc

Comment: i don't want to use an ID or the class .listThumb[ID]. if possible I want to keep it in common.

Comment: Solved:
`//bildSwap bei liste
  $(".listThumbs img").click(function(){
   //console.log($(this).attr("src"));
   var newImg = $(this).attr("src");
   $(this).closest(".item").find(".clistWrapper").css("background-image","url('"+newImg+"')");
  });`

Comment: Sorry, I mis-understood what you were asking when I saw about ID's! :)
Yes, the .closest method would be the best option, that'll traverse up the DOM and find the nearest .clistWrapper to the image that was clicked!